# Webdriver stops responding while getting response from server, FireFox

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I have trouble using `Firefoxdriver()`. When nant script is executed to run all tests, sometimes test cases aren't executed. In one random test case fails because Webdriver is waiting for respond from server, all next test cases fails.

FF is not responding anymore, Webdriver hangs.

Additionally, when all tests finish FF is not closed, but should be.

I think reason is that webdriver cannot handle request from server.

All tests when they are executed manualy separately works great, but when all are excuted in the script webdriver block.

In my case pages are responding.

- Firefox:11
- Webdriver: 2.0.19
- Windowx XP
- MbUnit Gallio, Nant
- c#

Can you please help?

log:

> OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: No response from server for url
>   http://localhost:7055/hub/session/573893ba-2a39-4da2-be57-33cf352a5945/element/%7Bd5b8fdf1-62fd-462b-b72c-3bc4f1be3100%7D/text
>   at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.CreateResponse(WebRequest
>   request) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   115 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor.cs:line
>   96 at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.Internal.ExtensionConnection.Execute(Command
>   commandToExecute) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Firefox\Internal\ExtensionConnection.cs:line
>   128 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(DriverCommand
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters) in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver.cs:line
>   795 at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.get_Text() in
>   c:\Projects\WebDriver\trunk\dotnet\src\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebElement.cs:line
>   96 at WebPages.TableGetRowData(String ctl_name, String name)

---

```
[FixtureSetUp]
        public void FixtureSetup()
        {
       {

         FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                        driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);



                        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(timetowait)));
                        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(seleniumBrowserUrl + "/admin/Login/Login.aspx");
}

     [Test]
            [Category(TestCategory.Smoke)]
            [Category(TestCategory.Smoke_Players)]
            [Metadata(UserStory.Name, UserStory.AP_Wallet)]
            public void DeductMoneyFromWallet()
            {
                struct_Wallet structWalet;

                structWalet.Amount = "100,10";
                structWalet.Direction = "Debit";
                structWalet.Type = "Manual";
                structWalet.reason = "Reason Deduct Money";
                structWalet.id = "";


                DefaultPage defpage = webdrivertester.DefaultPage();
                struct_PlayerGridRow player = defpage.ClickFindPlayers()
                    .PresButtonSearch()
                    .SelectFisrtPlayer()
                    .ClickEditWalet()
                    .getAmount()
                    .SelectDeductFromWallet()
                    .TypeInputAmount(structWalet.Amount)
                    .TypeInputReason(structWalet.reason)
                    .ClickSumbitWalet()
                    .ClickWaletPopupOK()
                    .DeductValue()
                    .AssertWallet()
                    .getPlayer();


                structWalet.Username = player.username;
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(seleniumBrowserUrl + "/admin/default.aspx");

                DefaultPage defpage1 = webdrivertester.DefaultPage();
                defpage1.ClickMoney()
                    .ClickFundsTransactionLog()
                    .TypeInputUsername(structWalet.Username)
                    .Clicksearch()
                    .ReadFirstrowData()
                    .AssertRowWithWallet(structWalet);

            }
```

it stops in this method ".DeductValue()", After popup is clicked with "OK". Webdriver blocks, Webdriver  wait response from server, After stopping tests FF works normally, page is reloaded. No error is returned. This test doen't work when complete TestFixture is ran, when i run only this test works OK.

---

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(WebDriver, ts);
            wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(ctl_name)));
```

I add wiat in my code where i exepct page refresh ( button click, link click,...)
but sometimes works sometimes does not for same test case. 
fopr 100 test case i spen 6 day for partial solwing this problem i spend 2 days, feel like in stoneage

Comment: If you want help we require code.  The exception indicates the url is not valid.

Comment: Yes if i stop running tests and FF is blocked, after stoping tests FF works normally, can be clickable. Test case when is ran works correct, and Webdriver does not hang.

Comment: i have same poblem with selenium 1 RC and now  also with webdriver have same problems, I'm testing aspx pages, when Popups are displayed, AJAX is used. For exmaple i choose Ruby- Watir, i did not have any problems with same identical test cases. Selenium always creshed and now is happening again.

Comment: web driver profile is saved into folder C:\Documents and Settings\danijelv\Local Settings\Temp\anonymous209841136.webdriver-profile.  Size of profile fodler is 27,5MB

Comment: I edited your original question for formatting and clarity. Please, do not post follow up information as answers, edit your question instead.